# How to sort data sets Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, sorting

I have some data here

```
 VAN,Ford,Transit,7995
 VAN,Ford,Transit,8900
 VAN,Ford,Transit,6200
```

I have already split the data but I need to order them from cheapest van first and I have no idea where to start. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;


public class Vehicle {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
    {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/java/car_file.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String text = "";
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line!= null)
        {
            text += line+"\r\n";
            line = reader.readLine();
        }

        System.out.println(text);       
    }
}
```

I am guessing you make classes and sort the data some how but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Start by creating a class for you data containing fields for the values that you have (VAN,For,Transit,7995). Then put them in a Collection. Create a Comparator that will sort on the price field and use it with the sort() method.

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg Why don't you post an answer instead? :)

Comment: @Joffrey - I could but the asker asked for general direction so :)

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg I didn't mean "post a full answer implementing what you saiud here", I meant you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Joffrey ah yes, maybe I should - doesn't matter for me as long as the asker is satisfied :)

Comment: @PeterLiljenberg It matters for future readers if your answer is better than others, but not visible because it can't be accepted ;) That's probably why they discourage answers in comments in the Help Center.

Comment: I think my answer is better than the (currently) accepted answer.

Comment: @Joffrey you're right - I stand corrected. However there are a lot of answers already so I don't think I will create a new one now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, let's parse the lines from your file into Car objects instead of putting them in one big String:

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception
{
    FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/java/car_file.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
    List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
    String line = reader.readLine();
    while (line!= null)
    {
        cars.add(new Car(line));
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
}

public class Car {
    private String type;
    private String brand;
    private String model;
    private int price;

    public Car(String spec) {
        String[] parts = spec.split(",");
        if (parts == null || parts.length != 4) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad car specification: " + spec);
        }
        int i = 0;
        type = parts[i++];
        brand = parts[i++];
        model = parts[i++];
        price = Integer.parseInt(parts[i++]);
   }

   public int getPrice() {
        return price;
   }

   // other getters and setters could go here

   public String toString() {
       return String.format("Car type=%s, brand=%s, model=%s, price=%s", type, brand, model, price);
    }
}
```

Now we need to sort them. One way to do this is implement a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). One of the other answers describes another way to do this by letting the Car class implement [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). The reason I didn't choose that solution is that it only allows one sorting order for cars. If you later want to be able to sort by something else too then that would not be possible using Comparable. So using a separate Comparator is more loosely coupled and thus offers more flexibility.

If you look at the JavaDoc of Comparator's compare method (see link above) it says:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive 
>   integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

So we must return a negative integer if the first argument is less than the second:

```
public class CarPriceComparator implements Comparator<Car> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Car o1, Car o2) {
        return o1.getPrice() - o2.getPrice();
    }
}
```

Now you can sort your list of Cars, for example by calling [Collections.sort](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

```
Collections.sort(cars, new CarPriceComparator());
```

And print the result:

```
for(Car car : cars) {
    System.out.println(car);
}
```

Note: I implemented toString in Car, otherwise the above code would only print the object references of the cars.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create a class for the vehicles containing suitable members, in your case three of type `String` and one of type `int`, which would be the `Price`. Then a new instance would be generated for each line read from the textfile, populating the members. The new instances should be put into a container. You would also have to implement a comparator which can decide the order of instances - in your case, it would examine the `Price` of two instances and return perhaps the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example i found using comparable

```
     public class Employee implements Comparable {

int EmpID;
String Ename;
double Sal;
static int i;

public Employee() {
    EmpID = i++;
    Ename = "dont know";
    Sal = 0.0;
}

public Employee(String ename, double sal) {
    EmpID = i++;
    Ename = ename;
    Sal = sal;
}

public String toString() {
    return "EmpID " + EmpID + "\n" + "Ename " + Ename + "\n" + "Sal" + Sal;
}

public int compareTo(Object o1) {
    if (this.Sal == ((Employee) o1).Sal)
        return 0;
    else if ((this.Sal) > ((Employee) o1).Sal)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
```

}

And the test class

```
     import java.util.*;
```

public class ComparableDemo{

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List ts1 = new ArrayList();
    ts1.add(new Employee ("Tom",40000.00));
    ts1.add(new Employee ("Harry",20000.00));
    ts1.add(new Employee ("Maggie",50000.00));
    ts1.add(new Employee ("Chris",70000.00));
    Collections.sort(ts1);
    Iterator itr = ts1.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext()){
        Object element = itr.next();
        System.out.println(element + "\n");

    }

}
```

}

**Output**:

EmpID 1
Ename Harry
Sal20000.0

EmpID 0
Ename Tom
Sal40000.0

EmpID 2
Ename Maggie
Sal50000.0

EmpID 3
Ename Chris
Sal70000.0

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Tested and Executed. In order to implement this, `line.split(",")[3];` plays the key role if you observe keenly.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ArrageItInOrder{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
        String filePath="C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/java/car_file.txt";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        Map<String, String> map=new TreeMap<String, String>();
        String line="";
        while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
            map.put(getField(line),line);
        }
        reader.close();
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filePath);
        for(String val : map.values()){
            writer.write(val);  
            writer.write('\n');
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    private static String getField(String line) {
        return line.split(",")[3];//extract value you want to sort on
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

class Vehicle implements Comparable<Vehicle>{
    private final String type;
    private final String manufacturer;
    private final String model;
    private final int number;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FileReader file = new FileReader("C:/Users/Aaron/Documents/java/car_file.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);
        String line;
        String[] fields;
        ArrayList<Vehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
        while ((line=reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fields=line.split(",");
            vehicleList.add(new Vehicle(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], Integer.parseInt(fields[3])));
        }
        Collections.sort(vehicleList);
        for (Vehicle v : vehicleList) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }

    public Vehicle(String type, String manufacturer, String model, int number) {
        this.type = type;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.model = model;
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vehicle other) {
        int comparison = this.type.compareTo(other.type);
        if (comparison == 0) comparison=this.manufacturer.compareTo(other.manufacturer);
        if (comparison == 0) comparison=this.model.compareTo(other.model);
        if (comparison == 0) comparison=this.number-other.number;
        return comparison;        
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return type+","+manufacturer+","+model+","+number;
    }
}
```